# Ruby Selenium Webdriver - Need to wait / sleep while page redirects (refreshes)

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the Ruby `selenium-webdriver` gem to create a web-crawling/scraping script. The page that I'm scraping is loaded via AJAX and displays information for a certain account. If you select a second account number on a dropdown menu, the page redirects very briefly to another URL and back to the original URL, just with different information loaded via AJAX. I want to be able to scrape info for both the account numbers listed on the dropdown options. The problem is that Selenium performs the scrape faster than the page can redirect/reload on the dropdown click, so I don't end up getting the second account's information.

```
def crawl_page
  browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
  browser.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10 # seconds 
  browser.navigate.to 'http://www.foobar.com'
  account_dropdown = Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(browser.find_element(:id, 'account'))
  account_dropdown.options.each do |option|
    option.click
    wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) # seconds
    # this wait is not working because option is selected before redirect/refresh:
    wait.until { option.selected? }
    html = browser.page_source
    scrape_page(html)
  end
  browser.quit  
end
```

I've tried putting a `sleep(3)` on the line after the click, but get the following error message:

```
[remote server] resource://fxdriver/modules/web_element_cache.js:8180:in `fxdriver.cache.getElementAt': Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError)
```

I've also tried using Selenium's explicit `wait` code, but the ids of the elements appear to dynamically change on the updated page so something like:

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) # seconds
wait.until { browser.find_element(:id, 'titlexyz').displayed? }
```

results in an error message that says it's timed out and can't find the element:

```
~lib/selenium/webdriver/common/wait.rb:57:in `until': timed out after 10 seconds (Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"titlexyz"}) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::TimeOutError)
```

Is there some way to get it to sleep or wait without having to look for a specific element on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I finally figured it out thanks to SiKing's answer. The trick was to count the number of options for the dropdown menu, and put that into a `.times` loop. Then on each iteration, I instantiated a new Selenium object for the dropdown menu, found the correct option number and clicked it. I also put the script to sleep for 5 seconds to give it a chance to do the reload/redirect.

```
def crawl_page
  browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
  browser.navigate.to 'http://www.foobar.com'
  account_dropdown = Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(browser.find_element(:id, 'account'))

  count = account_dropdown.options.count
  count.times do |option_num|
    account_dropdown = Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(browser.find_element(:id, 'account'))
    account_dropdown.options[option_num].click
    sleep 5
    html = browser.page_source
    scrape_page(html)
  end

  browser.quit  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not do ruby, so I cannot help you with the ruby syntax.

Every time a page reloads (in your code every time you do `option.click`), all WebElements (your `account_dropdown.find_elements(:css, 'option')`) that you have are no longer valid! You will have to base your loop on something else - perhaps the count of the items in the pulldown - and find each of the elements you want to interact with *inside* the loop!

Comment: Thanks, but if I put a `puts option.text` right after the `option.click` line of code, it will correctly display the correct text. (I can also run `p option` and they are different element ids.) So it does seem to keep at least those elements in memory long enough to do the loop. The problem is that the new browser page hasn't loaded before I grab its `page_source`.

Comment: Would be kool to see the page you are talking about. Until then, this is all just guesswork.

Comment: Sorry, no can do. It would involve giving you one of our client's logins, and we don't have a test account setup for this. I do think you're right though. I think the elements only stay in memory long enough to do something quickly with them, but as soon as the page redirects, it's lost. I'll try the option count idea.

Comment: Oddly, I can use the existing loop to get the option values as strings and store them in an array, but as soon as I use them in a new loop to try to iterate through and find each option on the page with that value, then click it, I end up with a error message saying `The given selector option[value='foobar' is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement.`